# Remove item in list

Tags: python, list

For an assignment, I want to remove all undesirable items in a list. This is an example of code that should remove all 1's from a list; however, when I run it, it returns None. Why is this?

```
v=[1,2,1,3,1,4,5,55,1]

for i in v:
    if i==1:
        result=v.remove(1)
    else:
        continue
print (result)
```

Comment: It happens in place.  print `v`

Comment: you can also do: `while 1 in v: v.remove(1)`

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html  (`list.remove(x)`) (as @pylang secified).

Comment: Dup of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating. Dont know HTF did I miss it the 1st time...

Answer (score 0):

`list.remove()` mutates the list *in-place*.  The [method itself returns `None`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm).  Print `v` to see results.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`. [1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your list:

Python 2:

```
v = filter(lambda x: x != 1, v)
```

Python 3:

```
v = filter((1).__ne__, v)
```

The code snippet in the question is basically equivalent to:

```
while 1 in v: 
    v.remove(1)
```